# How to use a library's code in IntelliJ instead of the jar file

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, module, jar

I'm using gradle for my build tool. I have a project that uses a jar file and I have the jar file imported into my gradle for my project which works great when doing build and deploy.

Problem is that I'm developing the jar file along with the project. When I change the library code, I have to build and move the jar file into my project. PITA.

Instead, I'd like to set up my IntelliJ environment so it uses the module's code first and then looks at the jar file later/never.

It seems like something that IntelliJ should be set up to do, but searching turned up nothing and I can't seem to find anything banging around in the IDE.

Anyone tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently such setup is not supported for Gradle project. There is however a hidden option that you may try to set:

```
external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true
```

via "Help | Edit Custom Properties" and restart.

The corresponding request for this is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134885

Comment: Working in IntelliJ 2021.1